# What went wrong in proving $i=1$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, radicals, fake-proofs

I started with

$$x=(-16)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$x=(-16)^{\frac{2}{4}}$$

Since $$(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$$ we have:

$$x=((-16)^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

$$x=((16^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$

$$x=\sqrt{16}=4$$

Hence $$(-16)^{\frac{1}{2}}=4i=4$$

$$i=1$$

Comment: If $m$ or $n$ are not integers and $a<0$ the formula $a^{mn}=(a^m)^n$ is false. In fact, for $a<0$ and $r\in \Bbb Q$ the meaning of $a^r$ is undefined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ does not hold in general except in special situations such as:

- $a$ is a positive real and $b,c$ are real, or
- $a$ is arbitrary and $b,c$ are integers.

For example: $((-1)^2)^{1/2} = 1$, but $(-1)^{2\cdot 1/2}=-1$.

Or: $(e^{2\pi i})^{i} = 1^i = 1$, but $e^{2\pi i\cdot i} = e^{-2\pi} \approx 0.002$.

Answer (score 2):

The imaginary numbers invalidate some of the usual rules on the exponents.

In the first place,

$$i^2<0.$$

Answer (score 0):

For positives a and b,
$\sqrt{-a} \sqrt{-b} \not = \sqrt{ab} $
But,
$\sqrt{-a} \sqrt{-b} = - \sqrt{ab} $